# TextBox Not Honoring Value Returned By Get

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, textbox

Have a TextBox that I want to limit the input range.
In this simple example Int32 from 0 to 300.
In real life the range is more complex and I don't want to get the UI involved other than receive back and display a valid value.

If I enter 333 it get returns 300 and 300 is in the TextBox.

Here is the problem:
Then if I add a digit for 3001 the set assigns a value of 300.
get is called and returns 300.
But 3001 is still in the TextBox.

If I paste 3001 then it properly displays 300.
It is only when a single key strokes makes 4 (or greater) digits that it fails.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LimitInt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="60" Height="20"/>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private Int32 limitInt = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Int32 LimitInt
    {
        get { return limitInt; }
        set
        {
            if (limitInt == value) return;
            limitInt = value;
            if (limitInt < 0) limitInt = 0;
            if (limitInt > 300) limitInt = 300; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LimitInt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement validation. Look a [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Pretend I don't want to use validation.  Why is the value return by get not that value in the UI?  301 displays 300.  -1 displays 0.  But 3001 displays 3001.

Comment: I'm not getting the same problem... I copy/pasted your code and when I press `1` for `3001` it gives me `300`.

Comment: @Bob. I tried on another box and same problem.  .NET 4.0 Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Hmm... you're right, I think its a .NET thing. I used .NET 4.5 and it works, but in .NET 4.0 it doesn't.

Comment: @Bob. Another reason to go to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3):

I believe this happens because you are changing the value of the binding source in the middle of the binding operation.  When you use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the binding, you are telling it to re-evaluate on each keypress.  And in that case, the `Binding` is pushing the value to the source, not attempting to update the target by pulling from the source.

Even after you raise your NotifyPropertyChanged, I imagine that because you're in the middle of the binding operation, the Target doesn't get updated.

You can resolve this by just removing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` and leaving it at as the default (`LostFocus`).  Doing this will work as long as you're comfortable with it happening after the user tabs out.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LimitInt}" Width="60" Height="20"/>
```

(Mode=TwoWay is the default on the TextBox, so you can remove that as well).

If you want to evaluate it on each keypress, I would suggest looking into masked editing, and handling the keypress/keydown so that you're preventing values from being entered into the `TextBox`, not trying to change them after they've been entered.

Comment: I don't agree with your assertion "not attempting to update the target by pulling from the source".  Get is called and returns the proper value.  -1 is properly displayed as 0.  301 is properly displayed 300.   Get on 3001 set properly returns 300 but the UI does not display 300.

Comment: I haven't debugged the framework code, so I'm speculating here and struggling to explain clearly, but I'm not trying to say that the Source is never pulled at all - the NotifyPropertyChanged will force it to call the get - but this happens during the process of pushing the new value to the Source and while the TextBox is still processing the text input.  Without stepping through the framework, my guess is that the either the pull is discarded by the target because it is in the middle of a push operation, or the target value is "locked" while it is pushing to the Source.

Comment: Thanks.  If I go with LostFocus it works.  Not really the effect I want.  I will try out validation as suggest by Perrenoud.  +1

Answer (score 1):

It is a better to use validation.

Here's how:

Define your XAML to check on `PreviewTextInput`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LimitInt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewTextInput="CheckNumberValidationHandler" Width="60" Height="20"/>
```

Then set your Validation Handler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check to make sure the input is valid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void CheckNumberValidationHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
    if(IsTextAllowed(e.Text)) {
    Int32 newVal;
    newVal = Int32.Parse(LimitInt.ToString() + e.Text);
    if(newVal < 0) {
        LimitInt = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if(newVal > 300) {
        LimitInt = 300;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    }
    else {
    e.Handled = true;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if Text is allowed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text) {
    Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
    return !regex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

Edit: I checked, and it works in .NET 4.0 :)

Comment: I suspect this is correct so giving it a +1.  But for now I am going with LostFocus.  Until I test it cannot give it the check.

Comment: @Blam No worries, it really is a better way, since using `PreviewTextInput` can prevents the value from being entered, instead of checking after the value has been assigned.